# Fetching first two values of a column into two different variables in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

suppose table_1 consists of one column(table_no) and select * from table_1 gives you 5 values of table_no. now i want to store first two values of table_no into two different variables. How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: You can run a loop where you select only 2 records and then assign value to the two variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MIN and MAX functions, if you need only 2 values. Like this:

```
DECLARE
  var1 NUMBER;
  var2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT MIN(table_no), MAX(table_no) INTO var1, var2 FROM
     (SELECT table_no FROM (SELECT table_no FROM table_1 ORDER BY table_no ) 
      WHERE rownum <= 2);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create table t as select trunc(dbms_random.value(1,20)) x from dual connect by level <= 5;

Table created.

SQL> select * from t;

         X
----------
        10
        13
         8
        10
        16

SQL> select
  2    max(decode(rn,1,x)),
  3    max(decode(rn,2,x))
  4  from
  5   ( select row_number() over ( order by x ) rn, x from t ) ;

MAX(DECODE(RN,1,X)) MAX(DECODE(RN,2,X))
------------------- -------------------
                  8                  10
```